# How to iterate array of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My data looks like below:

```
 {
    "_id": "processedSKU_ID-1",
    "clientName": "fairmont",
    "searchQueryAnalysisObj": [{
        "searchKeyword": "iphone 1",
        "searchKeywordScore": 1.8000000000000003
    }, {"searchKeyword": "iphone 2", "searchKeywordScore": 5.400000000000001}, {
        "searchKeyword": "iphone 3",
        "searchKeywordScore": 1.8000000000000003
    }, {"searchKeyword": "iphone 4", "searchKeywordScore": 0.9000000000000001}],
    "_class": "com.unilog.model.MainClickStreamData"
}
```

I want to get all `searchKeyword` and `searchScore`.

I tried using:

```
for (var key in a)
    {
    
    a[key]['searchKeyword'].toString());
    
    }
```

but did not get anything.

Comment: In what format? Please share expected output format.

Comment: You can't access searchkeyword directly, as it is a property of objects in an array searchQueryAnalysisObj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do loop on `a.searchQueryAnalysisObj` like:

```js
var a = { "_id" : "processedSKU_ID-1", "clientName" : "fairmont", "searchQueryAnalysisObj" : [ { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 1", "searchKeywordScore" : 1.8000000000000003 }, { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 2", "searchKeywordScore" : 5.400000000000001 }, { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 3", "searchKeywordScore" : 1.8000000000000003 }, { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 4", "searchKeywordScore" : 0.9000000000000001 } ], "_class" : "com.unilog.model.MainClickStreamData" };


for ( var key in a.searchQueryAnalysisObj ) {
  //a.searchQueryAnalysisObj[key]["searchKeyword"] <-- Will return searchKeyword
  //a.searchQueryAnalysisObj[key]["searchKeywordScore"] <-- Will return searchKeywordScore
  console.log( a.searchQueryAnalysisObj[key]["searchKeyword"] + " - " + a.searchQueryAnalysisObj[key]["searchKeywordScore"] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = {
    "_id": "processedSKU_ID-1",
    "clientName": "fairmont",
    "searchQueryAnalysisObj": [{
        "searchKeyword": "iphone 1",
        "searchKeywordScore": 1.8000000000000003
    }, {"searchKeyword": "iphone 2", "searchKeywordScore": 5.400000000000001}, {
        "searchKeyword": "iphone 3",
        "searchKeywordScore": 1.8000000000000003
    }, {"searchKeyword": "iphone 4", "searchKeywordScore": 0.9000000000000001}],
    "_class": "com.unilog.model.MainClickStreamData"
};

var analysis = a['searchQueryAnalysisObj'];
for( var i = 0, n = analysis.length; i < n; ++i ) {
    console.log(analysis[i]['searchKeyword'], '-', analysis[i]['searchKeywordScore']);
}
```

Output:

```
iphone 1 - 1.8000000000000003
iphone 2 - 5.400000000000001
iphone 3 - 1.8000000000000003
iphone 4 - 0.9000000000000001
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the wanted peroperty `searchQueryAnalysisObj` with array for iteration.

```js
var object = { _id: "processedSKU_ID-1", clientName: "fairmont", searchQueryAnalysisObj: [{ searchKeyword: "iphone 1", searchKeywordScore: 1.8000000000000002 }, { searchKeyword: "iphone 2", searchKeywordScore: 5.400000000000001 }, { searchKeyword: "iphone 3", searchKeywordScore: 1.8000000000000002 }, { searchKeyword: "iphone 4", searchKeywordScore: 0.9000000000000001 }], _class: "com.unilog.model.MainClickStreamData" };

object.searchQueryAnalysisObj.forEach(o => console.log(o));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the property `searchQueryAnalysisObj` which is an array infact. And then use loop or map etc

```js
var obj = { "_id" : "processedSKU_ID-1", "clientName" : "fairmont", "searchQueryAnalysisObj" : [ { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 1", "searchKeywordScore" : 1.8000000000000003 }, { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 2", "searchKeywordScore" : 5.400000000000001 }, { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 3", "searchKeywordScore" : 1.8000000000000003 }, { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 4", "searchKeywordScore" : 0.9000000000000001 } ], "_class" : "com.unilog.model.MainClickStreamData" }

obj.searchQueryAnalysisObj.map((e)=>{
console.log(e.searchKeyword + " :: " + e.searchKeywordScore)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use forEach method like below:

```
var a  ={ "_id" : "processedSKU_ID-1", "clientName" : "fairmont", 
"searchQueryAnalysisObj" : [ { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 1", 
"searchKeywordScore" : 1.8000000000000003 }, { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 2", 
"searchKeywordScore" : 5.400000000000001 }, { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 3", 
"searchKeywordScore" : 1.8000000000000003 }, { "searchKeyword" : "iphone 4", 
"searchKeywordScore" : 0.9000000000000001 } ], "_class" : 
"com.unilog.model.MainClickStreamData" }
var b = a.searchQueryAnalysisObj

b.forEach( function (key, i)
 {
    console.log(key) //where key is each element of your array 'b'
});
```